# How do I export Typescript interfaces from a node module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, rollupjs

**Figured it out!**

Initially, I was trying to import my module like this:

```
const qml = require('quill-marking-logic')
const { checkSentenceCombining, checkSentenceFragment, checkDiagnosticQuestion, checkFillInTheBlankQuestion, ConceptResult } = qml
```

because I got a `TS2307: Cannot find module 'quill-marking-logic'` error when I tried to use

`import { checkSentenceCombining, checkSentenceFragment, checkDiagnosticQuestion, checkFillInTheBlankQuestion, ConceptResult } from 'quill-marking-logic'`

This was because I was using `"module": "es6"` in my importing app's tsconfig, which by default sets the `moduleResolution` option to `Classic`. By explicitly setting it to `node`, I was able to use the `import` syntax and get my interfaces!

**Original post**

I've built a node module using Typescript that I am using as a dependency in another app. I have a couple of interfaces in the module that I am trying to export from the its entry point so that I can use them in my other app, but they are erased after compilation. I understand that this is part of Typescript's design,  because the interfaces are used for runtime analysis, but I'm wondering if there's a way to get around it so I don't have to define them again in my other app and have to maintain the same code in two places. I'm using rollup as my bundler.

This is what the .d.ts version of my entry point looks like:

```
export { checkSentenceCombining } from './libs/graders/sentence_combining';
export { checkDiagnosticQuestion } from './libs/graders/diagnostic_question';
export { checkSentenceFragment } from './libs/graders/sentence_fragment';
export { checkFillInTheBlankQuestion } from './libs/graders/fill_in_the_blank';
export { Response, PartialResponse, ConceptResult, FocusPoint, IncorrectSequence, FeedbackObject, GradingObject, WordCountChange } from './interfaces/index';
```

That last line of exports is where the interfaces should be coming through.

Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es7"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types/"
        ],
        "declaration": true
    }
}
```

Here is my tsconfig for the app I'm trying to import this in to:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",        // path to output directory
        "sourceMap": true,          // allow sourcemap support
        "strictNullChecks": true,   // enable strict null checks as a best practice
        "module": "es6",            // specifiy module code generation
        "jsx": "react",             // use typescript to transpile jsx to js
        "target": "es6",            // specify ECMAScript target version
        "allowJs": true,            // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
        "lib": ["ES2017", "DOM"],            //
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true // Allow import React from 'react'
    }
}
```

And I'm pointing to the generated .d.ts file in the "typings" key in my package.json.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is possible.  To do this, `export` the interfaces you'd like to make available to consumers of your module in your module's entry point file:

```
// in entry.ts
import { MyInterface1 } from '/path/to/interface/one';
import { MyInterface2 } from '/path/to/interface/two';

export { MyInterface1, MyInterface2 };
```

Then, in your code that uses this module, you can do:

```
import { MyInterface1, MyInterface2 } from 'my-module`;
```

In order for this to work, you'll need to make sure the `declaration` compiler option is set to `true` in your module - this causes the compiler to output a `.d.ts` file that contains your module's typing information.

The last piece of the puzzle is to include a `types` property in your module's "package.json" that points to this `.d.ts` file:

```
{
    "name": "my-module",
    "main": "./entry.js",
    "types": "./my-module.d.ts"
}
```

For more information about preparing a module for publishing:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Comment: Hey Nathan, thank you for your help! I've updated my original post to reflect that I have all the code that you are indicating here, with one exception: is there a difference between the 'types' and 'typings' key for the package.json?

Comment: @E.Friedberg: Nope, you can use either - they are synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `--declaration` option to generate `d.ts` files for your module. The definition file will contain exported interfaces and you can use them in your application.

You should include the definition file with your module in a location typescript looks for definitions [in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html):

> Similarly a non-relative import will follow the Node.js resolution logic, first looking up a file, then looking up an applicable folder. So import { b } from "moduleB" in source file /root/src/moduleA.ts would result in the following lookups:
>
> ```
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB.ts
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB.tsx
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB.d.ts
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/package.json (if it specifies a "types" property)
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.ts
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.tsx
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.d.ts
> ```

Comment: Thanks Titian! I am using --declaration in my tsconfig and specifying the .d.ts file in my package.json, but the interfaces still don't seem to be coming through.

Comment: @E.Friedberg Are the interfaces exported from the module ?

Comment: I've edited the original post to show what my entry point looks like. The interfaces are not coming through.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"allowJs": false,
"declaration": true,
```

Add this to your `package.json` file:

```
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
```

Also, don't forget to put your `d.ts` files in a separate folder that you publish in your `package.json`, or they will be missed. For example, putting them in a `typings` folder beside the `src` folder and add this to `package.json`

```
  "files": [
    "/dist",
    "/typings"
  ],
```

For further details: https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/the-30-second-guide-to-publishing-a-typescript-package-to-npm-89d93ff7bccd